# Recommendation request: Reasoning behind statistics

Tags: statistics, philosophy

It seems, to me at least, that most Statistics textbooks focus on the Statistical methods and techniques, or on the mathematics behind them.

Would you recommend me some textbooks (or any online source) that discuss the "logical" reasoning behind the techniques?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in [Probability Theory:The Logic of Science](http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Theory-The-Logic-Science/dp/0521592712) by Jaynes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Statistics.html?id=mviJQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y (**Statistics** by Freedman, Purves, Pisani)
- [http://www.amazon.com/How-Lie-Statistics-Darrell-Huff/dp/0393310728](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393310728) (**How to Lie with Statitsics** by Darrell Huff)
- http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/106350.The_Lady_Tasting_Tea (**The Lady Tasting Tea: How Statistics Revolutionized Science in the Twentieth Century**
  by David Salsburg)
- http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/168872.The_Cartoon_Guide_to_Statistics (**The Cartoon Guide to Statistics**
  by Larry Gonick, Woollcott Smith)